Does General Relativity "break" Ergodicity?
Ergodicity is "the idea that a point of a moving system, either a dynamical system or a stochastic process, will eventually visit all parts of the space that the system moves in, in a uniform and random sense."
General Relativity tells us that gravity is self-reinforcing in that there really isn't a stable configuration for objects with just the property of mass.  While this is evident in discussions of negative mass, or systems with a mix of positive and negative masses, it is less intuitive in out real world until we realize that barring the effects of the other forces (especially the electromagnetic force), two positive masses without any induced structure from the other forces would simply collapse into a singularity (or I should add also without angular momentum, certainly a factor in general relativity responsible for structure). Or in other words, every positive mass generates an event horizon and unless something adds structure outside the horizon, everything collapses to a singularity.
With that observation, there are many who might say it is obvious that the Universe is non-ergodic due to the effects of gravity and by extension general relativity.
This seems to not be true in inertial reference frames without gravity.
So is it appropriate to think that general relativity break ergodicity?

Notice, that not all physical systems are ergodic
One problem is, that general relativity is not described by a dynamical system in the usual sense.
A dynamical system is some sort of group action
$$\mathbb R \times X \to X$$
where $\mathbb R$ represents time and $X$ is some measure space. In the context of physics $X$ ususally represents configuration of physical stuff. E.g., in Newtonian mechanics $X$ is the phase space of $n$-particles.
Now in general relativity there is no absolute time. So the meaning of the "state" of the system at a given time is not so clear.
You may consider the ADM formulation of general relativity, where time is treated separately from space. Here $X$ is the space of $3$-metrices $\gamma_{ij}$ and their conjugate momenta $\pi_{ij}$. But the dynamical system also depends on additional Lagrange multipliers.
These additional multipliers determine the hypersurface $\Sigma_t \subset \mathcal M$ of space time that correspond to time $t$ in the ADM formalism.
The question whether $(\gamma_{ij}(t), \pi_{ij}(t))$ has visited all parts of (configuration) space therefore depends on the Lagrange multipliers.
In general, there are systems which are not ergodic in any case. Consider e.g., cosmological solutions which yield eternal expansion, which is believed to be the case in our universe. In this case, already Poincaré recurrence fails, because the state of the system will never return to the early universe state.
